# EC2 Web server not accessible from desktop but accessible from mobile

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I started a web server on EC2 following the basic instruction on AWS website. The web page (index.html) since yesterday is not accessible through the browser (chrome & edge) but is accessible from my mobile. I have not made any changes to my desktop settings which should affect this.

Any pointers on how to investigate this would be great?

Comment: Are you accessing the web site via a Domain Name or an IP address? Is the desktop on a corporate network, or your home network?

Comment: Can you share the ``url`` ? check the ``http/https`` protocol

Comment: @programandoconro, Thanks a lot for your input. It was a http / https issue. http is working and https is not working. The default link of aws console is for https and hence it was not opening.

Answer (score 0):

Check your security groups and access control lists to confirm that you have not accidently allowed traffic to the page only from certain ip address/addresses.